# Install vue CLI in vsc - Faild

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, installation, vue-cli

what am I doing wrong here, trying to install VUE CLI in Visual Studio Code, and I have both yarn and NodeJs on my pc, as the tutorials tells me to.
I also logged in to my github and made a fresh repository.

( I am new to this)

This is what I get in the console when I am trying to install CLI (see picture). I am so confused!

Thanks for helping!
/Lisa

[printscreend picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CSDe.jpg)

Comment: As far as I can see installation went well.

Comment: but what about the warnings it is showing?

Comment: these warning are due to direct dependencies cli has. of course you can go ahead and report it to cli team. But should not impact your general RnD as such. You should still be able to proceed with your learnings.

Comment: oh. Ok, I will try to proceed with it then :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are more details about above?

npm audit automatically runs when you install a package with npm install. You can also run npm audit manually on your locally installed packages to conduct a security audit of the package and produce a report of dependency vulnerabilities and, if available, suggested patches.

detailed reference - https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities#running-a-security-audit-with-npm-audit